# Как называется эта иконка?

Tags: fontawesome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти название данной иконка. Мне нужно как компонент в реакте

Comment: Вы уверены, что это иконка из fontawesome?

Comment: Не знаю, ну хотя бы схожую на него

Comment: А что мешает вам просто взять эту самую картинку, которую вы вставили в вопрос, и поместить в реакт?

Comment: Нужно чтоб было в виде компонента, вдруг нужно изменить:  цвет, размер и .д и т.п Это не единственная   иконка будет на странице

Comment: Тогда отрисуйте в svg в любом доступном графическом редакторе, например